# Curl appending authorisation header but controller still 401

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the swagger gen ui and I am using the following settings and following this GitHub resource.

This seems to be a known issue with swagger according to GitHub, I am using a jwt barrer based token. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1425

I have setup my swagger gen as follows

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{

            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "bearer"
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                }, new List<string>()
            }
        });
   });
```

[image]

> curl -X GET "https://localhost:44396/api/BmiInformations" -H "accept:
>   text/plain" -H "Authorization:
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTAxOTMyNzQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyJ9.cbePeT9RJprvTWyQECiUCaoqjc25eFKtf7jh5DwOnU0"

But Still I am getting 401 unauthorised I am using a JWT based token that is valid.

```
private string BuildToken(LoginModel login) {
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["JwtToken:SecretKey"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    JwtSecurityToken token;

    token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["JwtToken:Issuer"],
    _config["JwtToken:Issuer"], expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
    signingCredentials: creds); 
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }

private UserModel Authenticate(LoginModel login) {
    UserModel user = null;
    //var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (login.Username == "mario" && login.Password == "secret") {
        user = new UserModel { UserName = "Mario Rossi", Email = "mario.rossi@domain.com" };
    }
     return user;
}
```

[image]

This is how am building up my filter.

```
 public class AddAuthHeaderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter {

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context) {
        if (operation.Security == null)
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>();


        var scheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "bearer" } };
        operation.Security.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
            [scheme] = new List<string>()
        });
    }
```

I have added to after my barrer bit. But its still not showing the word barrer

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppManagerDL.AppManagerDBContext>
 (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {              
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "bearer"
        });

       c.OperationFilter<AddAuthHeaderOperationFilter>();
```

**Edit 4**
Ok So now I have it showing Barrer correctly in the curl but its now saying the signature is invalid even though its getting the correct one from my appsettings.

> curl -X GET "https://localhost:44396/api/BmiInformations" -H "accept:
>   text/plain" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTAxOTc0MTcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyJ9.fLWxG1bRX6yCTqFe8XZbgL6Lh1RNcmVFX-636ZvqhNg"

My Settings in start up as as follows.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        services.AddDbContext<AppManagerDL.AppManagerDBContext>
          (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {

            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT"

            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
{
    new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
        Reference = new OpenApiReference{
            Id = "Bearer", //The name of the previously defined security scheme.
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
        }
    },new List<string>()
  }
});
```

The Exact error I am now getting is.

> date: Sat, 23 May 2020 01:04:11 GMT   server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>   status: 401   www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",
>   error_description="The signature is invalid"   x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Comment: You are missing the scheme before you add the  b64 enconded jwt in your authorization header. You need your header to look like: `Authorization: Bearer <base64 jwt  contents>`

Comment: What I can see in your CURL command is you are missing the word "Bearer" at the beginning, your header should look like "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX", something is missing in your AddSecurityRequirement configuration.

Comment: @MauricioAtanache that was it im stil having an issue please see the added code of AddAuthHeaderOperationFilter

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your current security definition with this :

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Scheme = "bearer",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    BearerFormat = "JWT"
});
```

Comment: Sorry but am i missing something u didnt explain the difference just dont copy and paste code without explaining.

Comment: Used a version that's working for me, sorry for trying to help. I hope you can fix it.